# Typescript - Class instance which implements generic type

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function which creates a class using a generic interface. The properties of the instance are set by a parameters of that generic, like this:

```
const ClassFactory = <T>() => {

    class MyClass {
        constructor(data: T) {
            for (const key in data) {
                if (!data.hasOwnProperty(key)) { continue; }
                (this as any)[key] = data[key];
            }
        }

        // other methods can be here
    }

    return MyClass;
}

const GeneratedClass = ClassFactory<{ id: number }>();

const myInstance = new GeneratedClass({ id: 1 });

console.log((myInstance as any).id); // logs 1
```

This runs as intended, however there are 2 problems

1. `myInstance` typings doesn't have the keys of T - I'm expecting `myInstance.id` to be a number
2. I have to cast `this as any` in the constructor to assign the values by the given data

In an attempt to fix the first problem I've tried various things I've seen from other posts, including
`class MyClass implements T`, but they all result in the same error: `A class can only implement an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.ts(2422)`.
I understand why it happens, however since `T` is known when defining the Class, is there a way for this to work?

If I have the data in a `public data: T` property, then `myInstance.data.id` is properly typed. So my question is, can this be done by skipping the `.data` part?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why `javascript` tag though ?

Comment: Try `return MyClass as { new(): T }`.

Comment: @JonasWilms thanks for the comment. By using `return MyClass as { new(data: T): T };` it's working properly for the example above, however if there is any method in the class it fails. Ideally it would just override the `new`, not the entire class.

Comment: I think if you answer your own question you should post it as an answer and not as an edit to the question.

Comment: @jcalz yes just did, thank you everyone for your time and your tips

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by Jonas Wilms's comment, I got it to work even if the class has methods/statics by returning

```
return MyClass as (new (data: T) => T & InstanceType<typeof MyClass>) & typeof MyClass;
```

Like this, all of the following are typed and run as intended

```
const myInstance = new GeneratedClass({ id: 1 });

console.log(myInstance.id, GeneratedClass.someStatic(), myInstance.someMethod());
```

However, this doesn't work properly if `new MyClass()` is used inside the class methods.

A workaround for it to be working is to create a static which returns an instance with the proper types

```
        // inside the class
        public static build(data: T): T & InstanceType<typeof MyClass> {
            return new MyClass(data) as T & InstanceType<typeof MyClass>;
        }
```

then the following was as expected

```
const myInstance = GeneratedClass.build({ id: 1 });

console.log(myInstance.id, GeneratedClass.someStatic(), myInstance.someMethod());
```

**Full working example**

```
const ClassFactory = <T>() => {
    class MyClass {
        constructor(data: T) {
            for (const key in data) {
                if (!data.hasOwnProperty(key)) { continue; }
                (this as any)[key] = data[key];
            }
        }

        public static build(data: T): T & InstanceType<typeof MyClass> {
            return new MyClass(data) as T & InstanceType<typeof MyClass>;
        }

        public static someStatic() {
            return 2;
        }

        public someMethod() {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    return MyClass as (new (data: T) => T & InstanceType<typeof MyClass>) & typeof MyClass;
}

const GeneratedClass = ClassFactory<{ id: number }>();

const myInstance = new GeneratedClass({ id: 1 });

console.log(myInstance.id, GeneratedClass.someStatic(), myInstance.someMethod());

const myBuiltInstance = GeneratedClass.build({ id: 1 });

console.log(myBuiltInstance.id, GeneratedClass.someStatic(), myBuiltInstance.someMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, and was able to solve it quite elegantly by simply ditching `new` and creating a generic static method `Class.create()` instead, where I instantiate and cast as the correct type.

```js
interface MyGenericInterface<T = any> {
  getTheThing(): T
}

class MyClass implements MyGenericInterface {
  // Make constructor private to enforce contract
  private constructor(private thing: any) {}

  public getTheThing(): any {
    return this.thing
  }

  static create<TypeOfThing = any>(thing: TypeOfThing) {
    return new MyClass(thing) as MyGenericInterface<TypeOfThing>
  }
}

const stringyInstanceWrong = new MyClass('thing') // Error

const stringyInstance = MyClass.create('thing')
const stringThing: string = stringyInstance.getTheThing()

const numberyInstance = MyClass.create(123)
const numberyThingWrong: string = numberyInstance.getTheThing() // Error
const numberyThing: number = numberyInstance.getTheThing() // Works!
```